# How do I put AWS Amplify project into CodeCommit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-codecommit

I am just starting to use AWS Amplify but can't figure out how you are supposed to commit the project to a source code repository so that others can work on the same project.

I created an react Serverless project 'web_app' and have created a few APIs and a simple front end application and now want to commit this to CodeCommit so it can be accessed by others.

Things get a bit confusing now because for the CI/CD it seems once should create a repository for the front end application - usually the source files are in the 'web_app/src' folder.

But Amplify seems to have already created a git repository at the 'web_app' folder level so am I supposed to create a CodeCommit repository and push the 'web_app' local repo to the remote repository and then separately create another repository for the front end in order to be able to use the CI/CD functions in AWS?

For some reason if I do try and push anything to AWS CodeCommit I always get an error 403.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK - I'll answer this myself.

You just commit the entire project to a repo in CodeCommit.  The project folder contains both the backend and the frontend code.  The frontend code is usually in the /src folder and the backend code (CloudFormation files) is usually in the amplify folder.

Once you have the CodeCommit repo setup you can use the Amplify Console or the amplify-cli to create a new backend or frontend environment.  Amplify is smart enough to know where to find the backend and frontend code.

Bear in mind that the backend amplify-cli code creates a bunch of files that are placed in the frontend folder (/src), including the graphql mutations and queries that will be used in the frontend code.

If you have set up CI/CD then any 'git push' will result in a new build for the environment you are in.  You can modify the build script to include or exclude rebuilding the backend - I think by default it will rebuild the backend if there are changed.

You can also manually rebuild the backend by using the amplify-cli 'amplify push' command.

Take care because things can get out of sync and it seems old files can be left lying around that cause problems.  Fortunately it doesn't take long to delete and rebuild and entire environment. Of course you may have to backup and reload your data first.  Having some scripts to automatically load any seed data for development or testing is useful.

There is a lot of documentation out there but a lot of it seems to be quite confusing.